# Barcode that can hold a large amount of data (50 mb)

Tags: qr-code, barcode, file-sharing, datamatrix

I am creating an app that allows you to quickly share a file (like a photo or video). It will work by generating something like a barcode, but it can be animated or anything. Just a scannable thing that can be used to shared large amounts of data. I know a QR code can only hold up to 3kb, but in this case I’m not limited to a static image. Anything that can be used to transfer data from a screen to a high resolution camera works. (However I don’t want it to upload the file to a server and then generate a QR code link to that file)

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

There are proof of concept implementations of larger data transmission via a sequence of QR codes, sometimes called animated QR codes.

A common theme is to combine the QR code segmentation with a fountain code such as [Luby Transform Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby_transform_code).

Examples:

- https://github.com/divan/txqr (Go)
- https://github.com/grantgustafson/qr_tx (Python)
- https://github.com/gre/qrloop (Typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a storage account somewhere and hold the data in that storage and your QR code needs to redirect to that storage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).